# Как вывести значения функции Javascript в HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Как вывести значение first_name в блок div?

```
function getInfo() {
    FB.api('/me', 'GET', {fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,email'}, function(response) {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response.first_name;
    });
}
```

Выводится в `<div id="status"></div>`, но после нажатия на Get Info, как это сделать без нажатия, а сразу?

Comment: что не так с приведенным кодом?

Comment: Да, не так составил вопрос, дополнил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
getInfo();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
// При загрузки скрипта
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Hello!!"; 

// После того как страница загруженна
function resultOnLoad() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Результат функции resultOnLoad!"; 
}

// По клику на кнопку
function resultToDiv() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Привет, мир!"; 
}
```

```html
<body onload="resultOnLoad()">
  <div id="result"></div>
  <input type="button" onclick="resultToDiv()" value="Click me!">
</body>
```

Comment: что-то не выводится значение в div result, странно

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function (){
  getInfo()
},false);
```